# Button long click does not work

Tags: java, button, onlongclicklistener, long-click

I'm working on a soundboard and I want to implement a long click to share the sound.

I am working with a `switch Case` for each button

```
 public void MainMMP(View view){
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
                MainMMP.release();
                MainMMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.xxx1);
                MainMMP.start();
                break;
        case R.id.button2:
                MainMMP.release();
                MainMMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.xxx2);
                MainMMP.start();
                break;
        case R.id.button3:
            MainMMP.release();
            MainMMP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.xxx3);
            MainMMP.start();
            break;
```

And now I want to implement the long click. I tried a lot of different code here but it is not working for me.
I do not know where to put the `onLongClick` statement and how.

Can somebody show me a working method and in case of long click it should just send me a Toast that I know the method works?

Comment: I posted you some code you might want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the OnLongClickListener where you want, in the onCreate method for example.

Try to use the following code:

```
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        //Your code

        return false; // True if you want to execute simple click code too
    }
});
```

Comment: But it should do for every button another action thats my problem

Comment: You could get the id of each button through the view. I don't really know if I am getting the point of the problem

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
    private View.OnLongClickListener listener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId())
           case R.id.button1:
             // Do something...
             break;
           case R.id.button2:
             // Do something else...
             break;
        // If you still want to get normal click callbacks return true,
        // if you do not then return false.
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code

```
Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button1.setOnLongClickListener(listener);
button2.setOnLongClickListener(listener);
```

**Or better this**

One common recommended way to get `onClick`/`onLongClick`/`whatever` callbacks is to make the `Activity` implement the callback interfaces.

```
class YourActivity extend Activity implements View.OnLongClickListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate(/* ... */) {
        // ...
        button1.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        // Same code as the one above
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried this method but I at this point

button1.setOnLongClickListener(listener); <- I am getting cannot resolve symbol for setOnLongClick...

Comment: Well I tried adding your first 2 codes but I am always getting the problem button1.setOnLongClickLister <- cannot resolve symbole

Comment: Lister? It's Listener. Check your spelling please.